# Phonegap IOS app, JSON parse error?

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, parse-error, php-parse-error

I am generating a json object from php with json_encode and consume it with JS. The JSON object is valid, i run it through JSON lint, but I am always getting a parseerror when it is consumed from the php file directly.

Now, if i generate a .json file and output the object there no error is raised.

Has anyone come across this problem? Any thoughts as to why this might be happening?

Thank you. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem with getting a parse error was that I was using a relative path to make the request. Once I switched to an absolute path the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try not passing the JSON object to the JS file but instead echo it out on the php file then tell js in an output function of some sort to pick it up1

eg
echo json_encode  // In php file

function(output){
('some element').html(output); //output is what is returned from the php file (the json)
}

Comment: That is what doesn't work when I echo out the JSON object the $.ajax request gives me parse error, but when I output the JSON object into a .json file and consume that with Javascript then it works fine.